# jquery flickr show certain sets in a collection

Tags: jquery, api, flickr

Okay, I'm battling with this. I've searched the site but couldn't find anything that would help me or steer me into the right direction, so I'm posting this.

What I'm trying to do is list sets in a SPECIFIC collection.
I can list my collections with the amount of sets in them using the same method just fine, but for some reason I just can't grab the title of those sets.

I'm using the [flickr.collections.getTree](http://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.collections.getTree.html) method.

Currently I'm using this piece of code to try to list the set titles in a specific collection:

```
var apiCall = "http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?format=json&method=flickr.collections.getTree&api_key=" + apiKey + "&collection_id=" + setID +  "&user_id=" + userId + "&jsoncallback=?";

    $.getJSON(apiCall, function(data){
        $.each(data.collections.collection.set, function(i, set){
            console.log(set.title);
        });
    });
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Figured it out after a bit more searching. Hope this helps someone else.

```
var apiCall = "http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?format=json&method=flickr.collections.getTree&api_key=" + apiKey + "&collection_id=" + setID +  "&user_id=" + userId + "&jsoncallback=?";

    $.getJSON(apiCall, function(data){
        $.each(data.collections.collection, function(i, set){
            $.each(this.set, function(){
                console.log(this.title);
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: Do you know why a second loop is needed here? Or, in other words, why the original piece of code didn't work?